# subquery select with multiple row value

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have this query

```
select oldvalue, newvalue from(select 'a' as oldvalue, 'b' as newvalue) as N
```

now the problem is i can only have 1 value each column when i want to have multiple value in column, i have tried using union all like this

```
select oldvalue, newvalue from(select 'a' as oldvalue, 'b' as newvalue UNION ALL 'c', 'd') as N
```

with this now i have a and c as oldvalue and b and d as newvalue, but with union all i can only have 2 max of value in each column, is there a way for me to have more than two value in each column

Comment: The number of columns which can appear in a select is not limited to 2.  Can you better explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: i want to make temporary table with 2 column, and each column can have multiple value, i want to add a value in a column not add another column

Comment: You're missing a `SELECT` immediately after `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh okay, one last question, can i have multiple union all select? like more than one union?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Note that you _don't_ need to repeat the alias you define in the very select in the union.  Subsequent aliases will in fact just be ignored anyway, only the first one matters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen alright thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Just writing in CODE what @TimBiegeleisen has mention in the comment.

```
  SELECT oldvalue, newvalue 
  FROM ( SELECT 'a' as oldvalue, 'b' as newvalue UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'c', 'd' UNION ALL
       SELECT 'e' ,'f' UNION ALL
       SELECT 'g' ,'h' UNION ALL
       SELECT 'i','j' ......
      ) as N
```